# Issue with running sudo command with python on plumbum

Tags: python, plumbum

I'm using Python 2.7 with the latest plumbum package from mac ports.

In general, plumbum works great. Though I'm having a heck of a time getting a sudo'd command to work.  I've setup my /etc/sudoers for the commands I want to run without having to be prompted, so that's fine.  I can run the commands manually without issue.

However, when I try the same from python using this:

```
sudo["/usr/local/some-magic-command here"]
sudo("-u " + sudoUser) # sudo user is userfoo
```

I receive the following error:

> plumbum.commands.processes.ProcessExecutionError: Command line: ['/usr/bin/sudo', '-u userfoo']
>
> Exit code: 1
>
> Stderr:  | sudo: unknown user:  userfoo

The user does exist, so not exactly sure what the deal is here.

Comments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no "-u userfoo" user. There is probably just "userfoo". Note: no `-u` prefix. Try:

```
from plumbum.cmd import sudo

as_userfoo = sudo["-u", sudo_user]
print(as_userfoo("whoami"))
```

Comment: I am having the same problem.

Comment: from plumbum.cmd import sudo
as_userfoo = sudo["-u", Stefan]
print(as_userfoo("whoami"))

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-98b9da792c7e> in <module>()
      1 from plumbum.cmd import sudo
      2 
----> 3 as_userfoo = sudo["-u", Stefan]
      4 print(as_userfoo("whoami"))

NameError: name 'Stefan' is not defined

Comment: i know I am a user because less /etc/pwd lists me

Comment: stefan:x:1000:1000:Stefan,,,:/home/stefan:/bin/bash

Comment: whether or not I capitalize my name, error is the same

Comment: NameError has nothing to do with a system user. It says that a variable is not defined in your code (the name is not bound). Add quotes around the name, to pass the arg as a string literal.